# What happens to non-time inputs into functions when you do a Laplace transform of them?

Tags: laplace-transform

This question pertains to engineering equations where the input into a function isn't "t".

Consider this one, it's describing rudder axle inertia:

$$J_t * \omega_t (t) = T_l (t) - B_t * \omega_t (t) + T_f * \omega ( \omega_t ) - T_sp ( \theta_t ) - T_l ( \delta_t )
$$
I can see how things like $ \mathcal{L} \,T_l (t)  $ become $ T_L (s) $ ...but what about the other inputs from theta and omega?

...or is the formula just misformulated or incorrect in some other way?

Apologies for my attempt at formatting not working.

Comment: You need `$`dollar signs`$` around math within a paragraph, or `$$` double dollar signs `$$` for separate centered math.

Comment: Thanks... It doesn't seem to work for my attempt at making a Laplace symbol.